# How do I set up pxe boot to use preseed

Tags: preseed, pxe

I have a working 18.04 kickstart installation using PXE. I'm trying to set up preseed (because there are issues with ks that I want to get around). That setup is below as well, but it doesn't use my preseed.cfg file. I've tried it with and without the url/checksum=, and also using a specified file vs. directory. What am I missing. Documentation seems to be a little vague here, or I haven't found the right documentation.

`LABEL Ubuntu
      MENU LABEL Ubuntu
      TEXT HELP
      Ubuntu x86_64 18.04.1 Physical Machine
      ENDTEXT
      KERNEL Ubuntu-18.04.1/linux
      APPEND ks=http://netinstall/ks/ks/Ubuntu/ks-18.cfg vga=normal initrd=Ubuntu-18.04.1/initrd.gz ramdisk_size=16432 root=/dev/rd/0 rw --`


`LABEL PreSeed
      MENU LABEL Preseed
      TEXT HELP
      Ubuntu x86_64 18.04.1 Physical Machine Preseed (not ks)
      ENDTEXT
      KERNEL Ubuntu-18.04.1/linux
      APPEND auto url=http://netinstall/ks/ks/Ubuntu/preseed/ vga=normal initrd=Ubuntu-18.04.1/initrd.gz ramdisk_size=16432 root=/dev/rd/0 rw --`

Answer (score 2):

Changing as below seemed to do the trick.

```
LABEL PreSeed
      MENU LABEL Preseed
      TEXT HELP
      Ubuntu x86_64 18.04.1 Physical Machine Preseed (not ks)
      ENDTEXT
      KERNEL Ubuntu-18.04.1/linux
      IPAPPEND 1
      APPEND hostname=unassigned locale=en_US.UTF-8 keyboard- 
configuration/layoutcode=us url=http://netinstall/ks/ks/Ubuntu/preseed/preseed.cfg 
vga=normal initrd=Ubuntu-18.04.1/initrd.gz live-installer/net- 
image=http://netinstall/ks/Ubuntu-18.04.1-x86_64/install/filesystem.squashfs 
ramdisk_size=16432 root=/dev/rd/0 rw --`
```